# Ultimo theme abandoned updating after magento 2.3.1?

Tags: ultimo

In reply to another question on StackExchange I read the following comment:

"Ultimo theme and the developer has abandoned updating after Magento 2.3.1"

Does anyone know if this is true as I am currently using Ultimo and plan to use it in future Magento releases.

Comment: you could have googled this yourself. https://themeforest.net/item/ultimo-fluid-responsive-magento-theme/3231798 2.3 is not listed as supported

Comment: Exactly, but I was hoping someone would know if it has actually been abandoned...or know if something is in the pipeline.

Comment: did you ask the theme developers?